# How to deploy Laravel 5.8 project inside another PHP project?

Tags: laravel, apache, deployment, multiple-projects

I need to set up my Larave project inside another PHP project to access that project using https://example.com/laravel-project

Because I need to use the same domain for the new Laravel project.

For that, I used apache VirtualHost configuration like below,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Wamp/vhosts/example"

    Alias /laravel-project "C:/Wamp/vhosts/example/blog/laravel-project/public"

    <Directory "C:/Wamp/vhosts/example">        
        allow from all
        order allow,deny
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now routes are working fine but query strings not working well. seems every url missing query strings.

`https://example.com/laravel-project?test=value`

But Laravel App didn't identify *test* query parameter.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you give a sample code that fails to get the query string parameters?

Comment: @dparoli 

`$test = $request->query('test');`

this is the sample method I used

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that someone can understand what you are asking. Also take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting an answer. Then, please update your question.

Comment: thank you @dparoli, I just solved *query string missing* issue. 
I was wrong about VirtualHost configuration. But the issue was in *.htaccess* configurations. I add my solution below

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not in VirtualHost configuration, It's in **.htaccess** file configurations. Updating RewriteRule with [[QSA]](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag, solved **query string missing** issue.

`RewriteRule ^ index.php?$1 [L, QSA]`